# Ajax upload only passes first file to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to upload multiple files in a single input field. So far, the code works but it's just sending the first file to the upload.php file. I'm using jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="carica" type="file" name="carica[]" multiple="true"/>
<button type="button" id="upload_sub" class="button">Carica</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#upload_sub").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "./src/upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: function() {
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append("carica", $("#carica").get(0).files[0]);
                return data;
                // Or simply return new FormData(jQuery("form")[0]);
            }(),
            error: function(_, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error");
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(response, textStatus) {
                alert("Success");
                console.log(response, textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
print_r ($_FILES);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [carica] => Array
        (
            [name] => prova.pdf
            [type] => application/pdf
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpvIlTeL
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 7234
        )

)
 success
```

Comment: Yes, it was exactly that! By the way the answer below shows an accurate solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the entire file list and send all the files

```
        data: function() {
            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $("#carica").get(0).files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                data.append("carica[]", files[i]);
            }
            return data;
        }(),
```

Comment: Saved my work. Thank you so much, I thought there was something wrong with `.get(0).files[0]` ,but since my knowledge of jQuery is very limited I didn't know how to act.